# MAAS Invalid SSH key

Tags: ssh, maas, openstack

I would like to setup a MAAS for OpenStack with Ubuntu 12.04.

Everything workes great:

```
marcel@ubuntu20:~$ juju status
2012-07-09 13:00:02,559 INFO Connecting to environment...
The authenticity of host 'node1 (10.110.11.71)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 29:42:2c:7a:ef:52:d4:f8:63:51:d8:a1:1e:a9:16:0e.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
2012-07-09 13:00:05,883 ERROR Invalid SSH key
```

I read some more people have this issu not sure if it is a BUG but I couldn't find a working solution...

I read [this posting with the same issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147714/invalid-ssh-key-error-in-juju-when-using-it-with-maas).

I added a root user to this file that I can access the nodes:

```
/var/lib/cobbler/kickstarts/maas.preseed:
```

Now I have access to the nodes and I created a user `ubuntu` with a password and copied the keys.

Now it lookes a little bit better I thought.

```
marcel@ubuntu20:~$ juju status
2012-07-09 15:43:12,130 INFO Connecting to environment...
Warning: the ECDSA host key for 'node1' differs from the key for the IP address '10.110.11.71'
Offending key for IP in /home/marcel/.ssh/known_hosts:1
Matching host key in /home/marcel/.ssh/known_hosts:8
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
```

A closer look showes me this issues:

```
marcel@ubuntu20:~$ juju -v status
2012-07-09 15:36:49,458 DEBUG Initializing juju status runtime
2012-07-09 15:36:49,469 INFO Connecting to environment...
2012-07-09 15:36:49,588 DEBUG Connecting to environment using node1...
2012-07-09 15:36:49,589 DEBUG Spawning SSH process with remote_user="ubuntu" remote_host="node1" remote_port="2181" local_port="43964".
Warning: the ECDSA host key for 'node1' differs from the key for the IP address '10.110.11.71'
Offending key for IP in /home/marcel/.ssh/known_hosts:1
Matching host key in /home/marcel/.ssh/known_hosts:8
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
2012-07-09 15:36:53,098:16474(0x7f0c16d58700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@658: Client environment:zookeeper.version=zookeeper C client 3.3.5
2012-07-09 15:36:53,098:16474(0x7f0c16d58700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@662: Client environment:host.name=ubuntu20
2012-07-09 15:36:53,098:16474(0x7f0c16d58700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@669: Client environment:os.name=Linux
2012-07-09 15:36:53,098:16474(0x7f0c16d58700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@670: Client environment:os.arch=3.2.0-23-generic
2012-07-09 15:36:53,098:16474(0x7f0c16d58700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@671: Client environment:os.version=#36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012
2012-07-09 15:36:53,099:16474(0x7f0c16d58700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@679: Client environment:user.name=marcel
2012-07-09 15:36:53,099:16474(0x7f0c16d58700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@687: Client environment:user.home=/home/marcel
2012-07-09 15:36:53,099:16474(0x7f0c16d58700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@699: Client environment:user.dir=/home/marcel
2012-07-09 15:36:53,099:16474(0x7f0c16d58700):ZOO_INFO@zookeeper_init@727: Initiating client connection, host=localhost:43964 sessionTimeout=10000 watcher=0x7f0c14b886b0 sessionId=0 sessionPasswd=<null> context=0x367e940 flags=0
2012-07-09 15:36:53,100:16474(0x7f0c118e2700):ZOO_INFO@check_events@1585: initiated connection to server [127.0.0.1:43964]
2012-07-09 15:36:53,100:16474(0x7f0c118e2700):ZOO_ERROR@handle_socket_error_msg@1603: Socket [127.0.0.1:43964] zk retcode=-4, errno=112(Host is down): failed while receiving a server response
2012-07-09 15:36:56,434:16474(0x7f0c118e2700):ZOO_ERROR@handle_socket_error_msg@1579: Socket [127.0.0.1:43964] zk retcode=-4, errno=111(Connection refused): server refused to accept the client
2012-07-09 15:36:59,770:16474(0x7f0c118e2700):ZOO_ERROR@handle_socket_error_msg@1579: Socket [127.0.0.1:43964] zk retcode=-4, errno=111(Connection refused): server refused to accept the client
2012-07-09 15:37:03,107:16474(0x7f0c118e2700):ZOO_ERROR@handle_socket_error_msg@1579: Socket [127.0.0.1:43964] zk retcode=-4, errno=111(Connection refused): server refused to accept the client
2012-07-09 15:37:06,443:16474(0x7f0c118e2700):ZOO_ERROR@handle_socket_error_msg@1579: Socket [127.0.0.1:43964] zk retcode=-4, errno=111(Connection refused): server refused to accept the client
2012-07-09 15:37:09,779:16474(0x7f0c118e2700):ZOO_ERROR@handle_socket_error_msg@1579: Socket [127.0.0.1:43964] zk retcode=-4, errno=111(Connection refused): server refused to accept the client
2012-07-09 15:37:13,116:16474(0x7f0c118e2700):ZOO_ERROR@handle_socket_error_msg@1579: Socket [127.0.0.1:43964] zk retcode=-4, errno=111(Connection refused): server refused to accept the client
2012-07-09 15:37:16,452:16474(0x7f0c118e2700):ZOO_ERROR@handle_socket_error_msg@1579: Socket [127.0.0.1:43964] zk retcode=-4, errno=111(Connection refused): server refused to accept the client
2012-07-09 15:37:19,589 DEBUG Retrying connection: Cannot connect to environment using node1 (perhaps still initializing): could not connect before timeout after 1 retries
2012-07-09 15:37:19,708 DEBUG Connecting to environment using node1...
2012-07-09 15:37:19,708 DEBUG Spawning SSH process with remote_user="ubuntu" remote_host="node1" remote_port="2181" local_port="60742".
Warning: the ECDSA host key for 'node1' differs from the key for the IP address '10.110.11.71'
Of
```

Comment: Is it possible that I messed something up with key copy? Btw DNS and Time is working correct

Comment: I think the failute is that there is no ubuntu user what can I do that it work ?

Comment: you will need patience whilst seeking support here, sometimes it can be a few days until you get a response.

Answer (score 2):

You should not have to manually add SSH keys when deploying with Juju.  There are a number of things that can go wrong at the deployment stage (and we're backporting some fixes to alleviate the issues).  Can you please take a look here https://answers.launchpad.net/maas/+faqs and see if either of the first two FAQs apply.

Answer (score 1):

Seems Juju wants to use the MaaS user 'root' not another named user - **Please note I have not yet attempted to repeat the error to confirm...**

I got the Invalid SSH Key message during my first test rollout (March 11, 2013) - checked the time issue listed above to no avail.

In the initial MaaS installation I created a MaaS user named other than root then installed JuJu and tried to get JuJu past this error -

To resolve the Invalid SSH Key issue I created a user named 'root' in MaaS then:

`sudo ssh-keygen -t rsa` to folder ~/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/MyUbuntuLoginName/.ssh/id_rsa - not the sudo default of /root/.ssh/id_rsa)

`chmod 777  ~/.ssh/` (not sure this was necessary - obviously not secure)

`sudo cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and copy result in the MaaS web gui to root/preferences/add ssh key

copied root's MaaS key into the /home/MyUbuntuLoginName/environment.yaml file

`sudo juju bootstrap` - wait (possibly a long time) for the machine to come online

```
sudo juju status
```

accept cert by typing `yes` when prompted

Success!

Again, I have not repeated the problem to confirm this is the root cause...

Mikrodots